# Can't Remove White MenuItem Border

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend, controltemplate

I'm using Expression Blend to design a menu with various sub-menuitems. Within those items have a white-ish border or background that is annoying and looks like something from WinForms. I can't figure out how to remove it. So far I have tried editing the template for the menuitem and restarting with just a grid but even the grid is placed within this border.

Screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

How could I remove that pesky white border? Any help and code implementations would be greatly appreciated (It's really stopping me from continuing my project.)

Comment: Are you able to post any of your XAML markup? It's difficult to diagnose the problem without knopwing what you've already tried.

Comment: It looks like you're picking up the `WindowBackroundBrush` that sits as the background for one of the parts of the submenu and by default is set to #fff (white) so you could probably either overwrite the StaticResource for WindowBackgroundBrush with a Setter or go edit the template, but would need to see some xaml to know for sure.